# xpath: how can I get if the category is Type then get the Villa

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Get the type of the house that is Villa:

```
<div class="property__feature">
    <h3 class="property__feature-title property__feature-title--b-spacing">Property Details</h3>
    <ul class="property__details-list">
        <li class="property__details-item">
```

Here is where I need to get the info:

```
<span class="property__details-item--cat">Type:</span>
Villa
// ***
```

Comment: Hi, try to make your question more clear. What have you tried?

Comment: it would make it easier if you provided a link to the website. Or at least copy and paste the DOM tree.

Comment: sorry for not being as clear as I should be. am trying to scrape Property Details in https://gplazarou.com/Property/Show/Residential-Building-Plot-For-Sale-in-Geri-Nicosia-id-80765. I already tried using .Its a bit hard to let you know what I have tried as I am sure is wrong and not what am looking to obtain. Basically I want to extract all the details under Property Details.Hope it helps!

Comment: Just to elaborate in case I need only to obtain the Type of the property (which in this case is Building Plot) how can I get only that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using client-side template rendering, so there is no xpath selector you can use to extract that element using Scrapy because Scrapy only deals with HTML, not JavaScript

That said, the data you are looking for is sent down inside the page, and thus can be extracted with a little massaging:

```python
def parse(self, response):
  import json
  model_json = ''.join(response.xpath(
     './/script[@type="text/javascript" and contains(text(), "var model")]/text()'
     ).re(r'var model = (\{.+\});'))
  model_data = json.loads(model_json)
  property_data = model_data['Property']
  """
{
  "Property": {
    "Id": 80765,
    "Type": 32,
    "Status": 1,
    "Area": {
      "Id": 32,
      "Name": "Geri",
      "District": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Nicosia"
      }
    },
    "IsForRent": false,
    "RentPrice": 0,
    "IsForSale": true,
    "SalePrice": 125000,
    "PriceIsPublic": true,
    "SaleVAT": 0,
    "SaleVATType": 1,
    "Description": "<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"mso-fareast-language: EN-GB;\">We are pleased to present the new project of under division residential plots in one of the most sought after areas of Geri. It is located in a quiet residential area, 3 km away from the General Hospital of Nicosia, 3.5 km from the Mall of Cyprus, 2.5 km from the University of Cyprus and with easy access to the motorway. The under division plot has an area of 565 sqm and it falls into residential planning zone &Kappa;&alpha;8 with 60% building density, 35% coverage, 2 floors and a maximum height of 10m.</span></p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"text-align: justify;\">Subject to VAT.</p>",
    "EnergyEfficiencyRating": {
      "Type": 1,
      "CurrentRating": 0,
      "PotentialRating": 0,
      "Key": null
    },
    "EnvironmentalImpactRating": {
      "Type": 2,
      "CurrentRating": 0,
      "PotentialRating": 0,
      "Key": null
    },
    "ShowOnMap": true,
    "Coordinates": {
      "Latitude": 35.119343,
      "Longitude": 33.407802
    },
```

If you want to convert those `"Type": 32` into `"Type": "Building Plot"`, you'll have to go the extra step of also extracting their `.init` data from the other `script` text

```python
json.loads(''.join(response.xpath(
    './/script[@type="text/javascript" and contains(text(), ".init(")]/text()'
    ).re(r'\.init\((\{.+\})\)')))
"""{
  "Resources": {
    "PropertyTypes": {
      "1": "Apartment",
      "2": "House",
      "8": "Commercial",
      "32": "Building Plot",
      "64": "Land",
      "128": "Industrial",
      "256": "Investments",
      "512": "Villa",
      "1024": "Mansion"
    },
    "PropertyStatuses": {
      "1": "Resale",
      "2": "Rented",
      "3": "Sold",
```

---

In the future, if you don't see the information you are looking for when you use the "View Source" of your browser (or in the output of `response.body_as_unicode()` from inside Scrapy), then it is being loaded dynamically and thus needs some special handling. *Most* of the time, that information is loaded via [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XHR_(XMLHttpRequest)) and you're actually *in luck* because reproducing that in Scrapy is usually painless and gets you out of the HTML scraping game entirely. This is one of those unfortunate situations where the data is being loaded dynamically, but from *within* the page, and thus the preceeding silliness is required.